# Codeigniter calendar class

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I'm trying to add links on all days of the calendar class but i don't how to do it:
the actual code allows me to add specific links like in this example, i would like to add linkk to every days...

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

$data = array(
           3  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/03/',
           7  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/07/',
           13 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/13/',
           26 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/26/'
         );

echo $this->calendar->generate(2006, 6, $data);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer

```
$this->load->library('calendar');
$month   = '2';
$year    = '2012';
$lastday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
for ($day = 1; $day <= $lastday; $day++) {
    $prefix = ($day < 10) ? '0':'';
    $data[$day] =  'http://example.com/news/article/'.$year.'/'.$prefix.$day.'/';
}       
echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month , $data);
```

Comment: This solution only adds hrf attribute, I want to add data attributes also, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a wihle loop or something:

```
$days = 31;
$day = 1;
$month = 12;
$year = 2013;
$arr = array();

While ($day <= $days) {
    $arr[$day] = "'http://example.com/news/article/".$year."/".$month."/".$day;
}
```

Comment: This solution only adds hrf attribute, I want to add data attributes also, how to achieve that?